# Can 役立たぬ replace 役立たず (with the meaning of "a worthless person")?

Tags: conjugations

I know that these forms differ in a sentence use case but what about standalone words? For this specific one when I looked it up on Jisho the ず form is the entry with the meaning of "worthless person" while the ない(ぬ）form is only shown as inflection of 役立つ so I thought that the ない form is only used for the meaning of "something being not helpful/useful" and not "worthless person" specifically. Can these words be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These words are not interchangeable. 「役立たぬ」「役立たない」 cannot replace 「役立たず」 to mean "worthless person".

As you know, the continuative form (連用形) of a verb can function as a noun, and there are quite a few established nouns, eg:

> 遊ぶ → 遊び
> 戦う → 戦い
> 皿を+洗う → 皿+洗い* → 皿洗い "washing-up"
> 物を+知る → 物+知り* → 物知り "knowledgeable person"
> 足を+[踏]{ふ}む → 足+踏み* → 足[踏]{ぶ}み "stomping feet", etc.
> <sub>(* 複合語/compound of [noun]+[noun form of verb])</sub>

役立たず also derived from the continuative form of a verb phrase. ず is the continuative form of the classical negative auxiliary ず (predicative form/終止形). (ぬ is its attributive form/連体形.) Some examples of established nouns:

> 役に+立たず → 役+立たず* → 役立たず
> 世間を+知らず → 世間+知らず* → 世間知らず
> 恩を+知らず → 恩+知らず* → 恩知らず
> 医者が+要らず → 医者+要らず* → 医者いらず
> 親知らず, [水入]{みずい}らず, 舌足らず, [土踏]{つちふ}まず, etc.
> <sub>(* 複合語/compound of [noun]+[noun form of verb])</sub>

So, the ～ず is the 連用形, and that's why 役立たず can function as a noun. Since it's an established noun, it cannot be replaced with 役立たぬ or 役立たない.

Also please note that the noun 役立たず is read やく**た**たず, not やく**だ**たず, while 役立たぬ, 役立たない are read as やく**だ**たぬ, やく**だ**たない as they are the conjugated forms of the established verb 役[立]{だ}つ (This だ is voiced due to rendaku, as you may know). Their pitch accents are also different:

> 役立たず - [やくたたず]{LHHLL}
>
> 役立たぬ- [やくだたぬ]{LHHHL}
>
> 役立たない - [やくだたない]{LHHHLL}